# Histogram with bash

Tags: bash

Currently I use:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    ((histogram[${#line}]++))   
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"

for length in "${!histogram[@]}"; do
    printf "%-1s %s\n" "${length}" "${histogram[$length]}"
done
```

to generate a histogram output. But if there are no lines of length, the output automatically omit them. Is there any ways to let the function do not omit those lines? Any ideas?

Comment: Clever script, but it's not clear what you expect the result to be. Can you provide an example of expected input and output?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you want to **print a zero for every non-occurring length** up to the max length? If so:

```
$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    ((histogram[${#line}]++))
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"

max=0
for length in "${!histogram[@]}"
do
    if [ $length -gt $max ]
    then
        max=$length
    fi
done

for length in $(seq 0 $max)
do
    printf "%-1s %s\n" "${length}" "${histogram[$length]-0}"
done
```

Example run:

```
$ printf 'x\nfoo\n' | ./test.sh
0 0
1 1
2 0
3 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash uses sparse arrays by default. E.g. here could be `holes` in the array. You can avoid them by initializing (filling) the array beforehand. Of course, you need estimate the max index. e.g. add to the top

```
histogram=( $(printf "%0.s0\n" {1..10}) ) # generate 10 zeroes
```

after when you will run like

```
printf "%s\n" 1 123 123 123456 | bash the_script
```

you will get:

```
0 0
1 1
2 0
3 2
4 0
5 0
6 1
7 0
8 0
9 0
```

**or**, if you don't want initialize beforehand, you need check the existence of the given member and do the cycle for each one

```
while read line
do
    ((histogram[${#line}]++))
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"

max=$(printf "%s\n" "${!histogram[@]}" | sort -nr | head -1)

for ((length=0; length<=max; length++ )) {
        val=${histogram[$length]:-0}
        printf "%-1s %s\n" "${length}" "$val"
}
```

e.g. for the above `printf "%s\n" 1 123 123 123456 | bash the_script`

```
0 0
1 1
2 0
3 2
4 0
5 0
6 1
```